# Handling distinct nested elements jaxb

Tags: java, xml, spring, parsing, xml-parsing

There are similar questions such as:

[Handling nested elements in JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148013/handling-nested-elements-in-jaxb)

but they don't exactly address the case when there are elements with distinct names on the same level:

```
<course>
    <name>Calculus</name>
    <grades>
       <A>Good</A>
       <B>Avg</B>
       <C>Terrible</C>
    </grades>
</course>
```

The number of grades is dynamic.

What's the pojo for the grades?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.dom4j.*;


Element selectEle = (Element) root.selectSingleNode("/*[name()='course']/*[name()='grades']");
        
        List<Element> elementsList = selectEle.elements();
        System.out.println(elementsList.size());
        for(Element element : elementsList){
            System.out.println(element.getText());
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).